# Don't turn on HDD until I manually do it

Tags: hard-disk

I have PC with `1000 Gb SSD drive` and `1000 Gb HDD drive`. I use SSD drive always and mount HDD drive very rarely, once a week.
Recently I looked to its Smart and see that it has `520 Start/Stop count` and `1800 Load/Unload cycles`. 
I believe that this is not very healthy for HDD. Is it possible to set up not turn it on until I do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Use this tool to turn off and on the power to a disk:

```
udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdX
```

Ref.: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/udisksctl.1.html

Comment: Thanks for the links it works. The only question - is it ok for HDD, cause this command gives next output:
`Error powering off drive: No usb device (udisks-error-quark, 0)`
But this answer does now answered for my question: if I reboot PC HDD will start again. How to avoid it?